# I cannot access to response object in a cloud code function in parse-server?

Tags: node.js, express, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I’ve searched a lot around and coudn’t find a way to access the response object of a cloud function in parse-server cloud code (I’m using parse-server version 3.10.0). I’m missing something?

This is a basic need for every express developer. How can I add response headers, change the response statusCode, sending different Content-Type, pipe stream data to response etc. etc?

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s not the purpose of cloud code functions. If you want to handle the express.js request/response by yourself for more customized usage, you can just mount custom routes or middleware to the app. Something like:

```js
const express = require('express');
const ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
const app = express();

const api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev', // Connection string for your MongoDB database
  cloud: '/home/myApp/cloud/main.js', // Absolute path to your Cloud Code
  appId: 'myAppId',
  masterKey: 'myMasterKey', // Keep this key secret!
  fileKey: 'optionalFileKey',
  serverURL: 'http://localhost:1337/parse' // Don't forget to change to https if needed
});

// Serve the Parse API on the /parse URL prefix
app.use('/parse', api);

// Any custom middleware that you want as you'd normally do in any Express.js app
app.use('/your-custom-path', yourCustomMidleware);

app.listen(1337, function() {
  console.log('parse-server-example running on port 1337.');
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Davi but I wanted to to it in back4App actually. But I've then read that you can activate the hosting option to be able to use express. Great job on back4App it's really well constructed!

Comment: Thanks! Just to make sure you've seen that, in Back4App, after you've enabled the hosting option, you can mount your custom endpoint/middleware in the `app.js` file, where the var `app` is already available.